# Firebase serve doesn't include other pages in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, yarnpkg, serve

I've got a React app using React-Router with the following in `index.js`:

```
render(
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/">
        <Main />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/privacy">
        <Privacy />
      </Route>  
    </Switch>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

When doing `yarn build` then `serve -s build`, I can visit localhost:5000/privacy and see the privacy page, but when I do `firebase serve` the same URL gives a 404.

My firebase hosting config is set to the build/ folder as well, so they should both be reading from the same folder. I can also see other updates to the `/` path just fine, it's just other links don't work.

So my question is: Why doesn't `firebase serve` include the other pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I seemed to have fixed my issue. Here's the steps that I took:

1. Rerun `firebase init`
2. Put `build` as my public dir again
3. When it asks to configure as a single-page app, **select Yes**
4. Complete rest as normal

After that, I ran `firebase serve` and could see my other pages at their right URLs.